# Cross-platform game engine/API that can play compressed audio simultaneously

Tags: android, ios, audio, cross-platform, game-engine

**Background:**

I've spent all day looking for an appropriate game engine/API to realize a little game idea I had recently. It's supposed to be a simple 2D pixel art game. Usually, I use Monogame to make my games but the problem is that I need to be able to play multiple songs (preferably .ogg) at the same time. Monogame only allows you to play multiple .wav files but these start adding up quickly (I'm already at 250MB with only five 3 minute songs). So I started looking for other solutions but I came up empty. GameMaker doesn't allow it, SDL_Mixer can't do it, Monkey X neither and SFML can do it but doesn't support mobile.

**Questions:**

- Do mobile devices (like iOS and Android) even support playing multiple compressed files simultaneously? And if so, how many can you do performance wise (as far as I understand it can tax the CPU quite heavily).
- Do you know of any cross-platform game engines/API's that support this feature?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into unity? As far as I see it supports: .mp3, .ogg, .wav, .aiff / .aif and so on. I believe you can play multiple .ogg files at once and that preformance shouldn't be impacted very much, however I haven't been working with sound in unity so I can't confirm any of these claims from personal experience.

Edit: refer to: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioFiles.html

Comment: Yeah,  suspected that Unity might be an option. I've just always felt that it's a  bit unnecessary to use such a big engine for a simple 2d pixel art game. If I can't find an alternative I'll probably end up falling back to Unity.

Comment: I am developing a 2d pixel art game myself and I feel that unity isn't really a bad choice and from what I have developed until now I can confirm that it runs smoothly even on budget android devices from 2012.